# window.beginSheet crashes when window is closed

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I am using Swift in Cocoa to open a modal sheet.  It displays fine, but when a button on the sheet is clicked, the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Here is what I do to display the sheet from AppDelegate.Swift:

```
  var preferencesController: PreferencesController?

  @IBAction func showPreferencesWindow(sender: AnyObject) {    
    if let window = window {
      let winController = PreferencesController()
      window.beginSheet(winController.window!, completionHandler:
        {(mr: NSModalResponse) -> Void in print("Closing: \(mr)")})
    }
  }
```

Here is the action for the OK button click (an NSButton on the sheet):

```
@IBAction func okButtonClicked(button: NSButton) {
    print("OK")
  }
```

When this button is clicked, the app crashes, even though it is not calling any code to actually close the sheet.

Thanks much in advance; have tried a lot of things and it has been frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late, but I spent few hours with such a problem and found the cause.

The problem is that winController is defined within showPreferencesWindow and will be destroyed when the method finish. Since beginSheet doesn't block thread, it means that winController will be destroyed almost immediately.

The solution is to use global preferencesController variable instead.

Fixed code:

```
var preferencesController: PreferencesController?

@IBAction func showPreferencesWindow(sender: AnyObject) {    
  if let window = window {
    preferencesController = PreferencesController()
    window.beginSheet(preferencesController!.window!, completionHandler:
      {(mr: NSModalResponse) -> Void in print("Closing: \(mr)")})
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I had this exact problem, and the issue was solved by storing the controller in a property.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have something wrong with your setup.

1 - Make sure "Visible at launch" is not checked for your PreferencesController's window

2 - Make sure your button is correctly connected to the action `okButtonClicked`, if you rename the function after connecting It to the button you need to go back in IB and reconnect

3 - Why do you have a property `preferencesController` in your `AppDelegate` if you're not using It?

[Here is a sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/452482/stackoverflow/Sheet%20Click.zip) doing pretty much the same you're doing which doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  I also got it working, here's an example:

```
var layoutPrefWinController: LayoutPrefsSheet?

@IBAction func showLayoutPrefsSheet(sender: AnyObject?) {

if let window = window {

  let windowController = LayoutPrefsSheet()

  window.beginSheet(windowController.window!, completionHandler: {
    (res: NSModalResponse) -> Void in
    if res == NSModalResponseOK {
    }
    else {
    }
    self.layoutPrefWinController = nil
  })

  layoutPrefWinController = windowController
}
```

}